# Is ICslQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, azure-data-explorer

I want to have multiple threads querying kusto on the same kusto ICslQueryProvider. is this thread safe?

I currently lock the resource, but would love to have things asynchronous

```
var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true");
var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("MyTable | count");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data) state:

> More concretely, to create an ADO.NET-like client allowing queries
>   against Kusto, one uses static methods on the
>   Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory class. These take the
>   connection string and create a thread-safe, disposable, client object.
>   (It is strongly recommended that client code refrains from creating
>   "too many" instances of this object, and instead create an object per
>   connection string and hold on to it for as long as it is needed.) This
>   allows the client object to efficiently cache resources.
>
> In general, all methods on the clients are thread-safe with two
>   exceptions: Dispose, and setter properties. For consistent results,
>   one should not invoke either methods concurrently.

So, yes, your `client` is thread-safe.